# Adding an item to a JList remove all other items

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlist

I need some help about adding items to JList. I work on some "library" kind of project. And I need to add readers to already existing JList. But when I try to add it, JList just resets, removes all the readers and starts adding readers to a new blank JList. But I don't need it to make new list but add it to the already existing one.

Here's my code:

```
listCtenaru = new JList(vector);
vector = new Vector<String>();

    FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream("myjlist.bin");
    ObjectInputStream oss = new ObjectInputStream(fos);
    listCtenaru = (JList)oss.readObject();

    listScroll = new JScrollPane();
    listScroll.add(listCtenaru);
```

and action listener event

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       String jmeno = pole1.getText();
       String prijmeni = pole2.getText();

       listCtenaru.setListData(vector);
       vector.addElement(jmeno +" "+ prijmeni);

       pole1.setText("");
       pole2.setText("");

       pole1.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are creating a new model each time you add a reader and you set it on your JList.

I think it will be better to use a ListModel which is more flexible and suited for your JList. See the Java tutorials : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Here is the javadoc for JList.setListData(vector) :

> Constructs a read-only ListModel from an array of items, and calls
>   setModel with this model.  Attempts to pass a null value to this
>   method results in undefined behavior and, most likely, exceptions. The
>   created model references the given array directly. Attempts to modify
>   the array after invoking this method results in undefined behavior.

It stated that you must not modifies the vector after a call on setListData() and it's exactly what you have done here.

Answer (score 1):

To add and remove items in a list, you can use a `ListModel`:

```
// To create:
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for(Object item : (Object[])ois.readObject()) {
   model.addElement(item);
}
JList list = new JList(model);

// To add:
model.addElement("New element");

// To save:
oos.writeObject(model.toArray());
```

Incidentally, it is generally a bad idea to serialize a whole Swing component (like a `JList`). Instead, you should just serialize the data in it.